# Should I rewrite the git history of a non-GPL project to remove GPL code that was later removed?

Tags: gpl

I have an MIT-licensed project that used to include a GPL JavaScript library which has since been removed.

Is there any legal necessity to rewrite the revision history to completely remove this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but:

The issue largely comes down to licensing *documentation*. There is no reason why your old revision could not be licensed under the GPL, but if you do not announce that it *is* licensed under the GPL, then it's functionally *not*, and those revisions are in violation of the GPL. You cannot even be given the benefit of the doubt that might be given to a young repository with no published license on the revisions ("I hadn't gotten around to putting one up yet, and I thought it would be obvious since I'm using GPL libraries...") , since your licensing documentation for that revision probably says that the project, as a whole, is under MIT.

Thus, the pathological person who downloads the old version of your code has received software that claims to be MIT-licensed but that is legally obligated to be GPL-licensed, which is a GPL violation.

I'm afraid you must eliminate the possibility of public distribution of your non-compliant revisions by removing them from your history.

Comment: I am not a lawyer either, but including GPL code does NOT mean your software is automatically licensed under the GPL; it merely means you're violating the GPL if it's not, and could be sued.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt True enough -- I have clarified my answer, and in so doing, completely reversed the result.